# Super resolution on amd

Tags: display-resolution, monitor, gpu, amdgpu

Greetings ubuntu members.

Im back to Ubuntu after many years, 5 of so. I was using windows because of my job position. On windows 10, i haved super resolution for my monitor (scaling) im using 2k monitor and i haved 3k x something resolution (i don't remember). Now on ubuntu im limited on real resolution. Any way to fix this, i tried to create custom resolution, but ubuntu is not accepting it. Everything is too big for me now.
Thanks!

Linux localroot 5.11.0-40-generic #44~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 26 18:07:44 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

AMD® Ryzen 5 3500u with radeon vega mobile gfx × 8

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Welcome back to Ubuntu! Could you provide a little more specificity for your problem? What resolution is/are your monitor(s) running at? What resolution(s) would you prefer? Do you not see lower resolution options in the Display Settings? With some of this information, it may be possible to offer a solution 

Comment: @matigo My current resolution is 2560 x 1440. On windows i haved more than 3k x something. It was option from a radeon software (enable super resolution).
My monitor is ViewSonic 32" VX3276-2K-MHD

Comment: What was the command that you were using when trying to set custom resolutions? If you're using `xrandr`, there is a `--scale` option. You could try something like `--scale 0.75x0.75` ... 

Answer (score 0):

This custom version of Steam/Proton enables you to run SuperResolution.
https://github.com/GloriousEggroll/proton-ge-custom#quality-of-life-patches